# Is it possible to see if a text file contains a button name?

Tags: vb.net

So im trying to add a security feature in my program where it will download a sting and depending on what the string contains it will disabled that certin button. For example the string would contain: BTNCaculate - Disabled and it would disabled BTNCalculate. Here is my code so far:

```
    Private Sub BTNEnabler()
    Try
        Dim Request As System.Net.HttpWebRequest = System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create("Dropbox link")
        Dim Response As System.Net.HttpWebResponse = Request.GetResponse()
        Dim sr As System.IO.StreamReader = New System.IO.StreamReader(Response.GetResponseStream)
        Dim Button As String = sr.ReadToEnd()
        'if button.contains(any button + " - Disabled" then
        'disable that button
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("You are not connected to the interent!", critical)
    End Try
End Sub
```

i need the code for the part with the ' Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it's possible. It looks like some code is missing from above? Consider this, *assuming* that `Button` is some text, *what* is to be done with it? **Do that.** And if it's not some text, fix that first.

Comment: I suppose the 'real question' is, "how can buttons be accessed dynamically".

Comment: So Button is the string that would contain what buttons in the form are disabled. i need to pretty much say whatever button it says in the string then button.enabled = false

Comment: The easiest way to do this is may be to create a List(Button) collection, and place the buttons in there. Then this collection can be *iterated* to check for the name and call Enable/Disable as appropriate. One could also use Form.Controls, but that'd require more checks as well as possible recursion.

Comment: So like for example: if the string contained "Button1 - disabled" it would disabled buttion1

Comment: So i created a List like so:  Dim ListButton As List(Of Button)
            ListButton.Add(BTNAddItem) and the rest of the buttons. Now how would i say if string.contains(any of the buttons in the list) then disabled the button that it says

Comment: "would i say if string.contains(any of the buttons in the list)". You wouldn't. You would test whether the `String` contained a specific button name multiple times. How do you do the same thing multiple times? That's one of the absolute fundamentals of programming so not something we should need to teach here.

Comment: i know how to check it multiple times. The whole point of this post was to see if there was a quicker way to do it and only check once.

Comment: @JakeTous It would be like this: 'for *each* button in the list, if the string contains the string button.Name + " - Disabled", then disable *that* button. So it's only one check, applied once for each button.

Comment: @JakeTous An alternative would effectively be the inverse operation of extracting the names from the string and then using those names to locate buttons; this is still fundamentally a *looping* operation: 'for *each* name found, find the corresponding button and disable it'

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Find` method to find control:

```
dim c = Me.Controls.Find("the button name", True).FirstOrDefault()
If c IsNot Nothing Then
    c.Enabled = False
End If
```